# Jasmine SpyOn Test is not working

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, bdd, jasmine

I am using Jasmine-Species along with jasmine for `GWT` .

I wrote a test which looks like this

```
feature('checking spy', function() {

summary(
    'In order to check how spy work ',
    'I should have a class on which i can work '
    );
scenario('Spy should tell me function is called or not ', function() {

    given('A Class to work on ', function() {
        window.signInObj = new SignIn();

    });
    when('I Spy on a function and call it ', function() {

        spyOn(signInObj, "fillForm");
        signInObj.fillForm("world",'hello');

    });
    then('Spy Should tell me that function is called or not', function() {
        expect(signInObj.fillForm).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
});
```

when i try to run this test in test explorer in vs it gives me this

```
Test adapter sent back a result for an unknown test case. Ignoring result for 'Feature: checking spy Scenario: Spy should tell me function is called or not '.
```

Is there a problem in my test or there's anything else

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a problem with Visual Studio , when restarted it . It automatically fix all things .